# Changing TPanel fontsize to fit the caption

Tags: delphi, fonts, delphi-xe5, tpanel

I am using Delphi XE5 and I have a TPanel

```
Caption: 0,00 USD
Width: 185
Height: 41
```

What i need to do is to change the fontsize according to text width / height to fit the panel.

Let's say the panel should show 1,25 USD, Fontsize will be 25 but if panel shows 1.425,18 USD the Fontsize will be 18 automatically. Is there anyway to change the fontsize automatically according to text size?

**EDIT:** Added untpanel unit

I have created the following unit. I am calling FitPanel everytime i update the caption. It works but it doesn't work PERFECT.

```
unit untpanel;

interface

uses System.Classes, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls;

type
  TPanel = class(Vcl.ExtCtrls.TPanel)
  private
    FScaleFont: boolean;
    procedure SetScaleFont(const Value: boolean);
  public
    procedure FitPanel;
    function TextHeight(Font: TFont; s: string): integer;
    function TextWidth(Font: TFont; s: string): integer;
    property ScaleFont: boolean read FScaleFont write SetScaleFont default false;
  protected
    procedure Resize; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TPanel }

function TPanel.TextWidth(Font: TFont; s: string): integer;
var
  b: TBitmap;
begin
  Result := 0;
  b := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    b.Canvas.Font.Assign(Font);
    Result := b.Canvas.TextWidth(s);
  finally
    b.Free;
  end;
end;

function TPanel.TextHeight(Font: TFont; s: string): integer;
var
  b: TBitmap;
begin
  Result := 0;
  b := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    b.Canvas.Font.Assign(Font);
    Result := b.Canvas.TextHeight(s);
  finally
    b.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TPanel.SetScaleFont(const Value: boolean);
begin
  FScaleFont := Value;
  if Value then
  begin
    FitPanel;
  end;
end;

procedure TPanel.Resize;
begin
  inherited;
  if ScaleFont then
    FitPanel;
end;

procedure TPanel.FitPanel;
var
  w, a: integer;
  c1, c2: boolean;
  pnl: TPanel;
begin
  pnl := Self;
  c1 := False;
  c2 := False;
  while True do
  begin
    w := TextWidth(pnl.Font, pnl.Caption);
    a := TextHeight(pnl.Font, pnl.Caption);
    if w < (pnl.ClientWidth - 5) then
    begin
      if c1 and c2 then
        break;
      if a < pnl.Height then
        pnl.Font.Size := pnl.Font.Size + 1
      else
        break;
      c1 := True;
    end else
    if w > (pnl.ClientWidth - 5) then
    begin
      if c1 and c2 then
        break;
      pnl.Font.Size := pnl.Font.Size - 1;
      c2 := True;
    end else
      break;
  end;

end;

end.
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll have to code that up. Use text measuring functions to check how large a specific piece of text is and tune the text size to make the text large, but not too large.

Answer (score 1):

Try and see if this is better:

```
type
  TPanel = class(Vcl.ExtCtrls.TPanel)
  private
    FScaleFont: boolean;
    procedure SetScaleFont(const Value: boolean);
  public
    property ScaleFont: boolean read FScaleFont write SetScaleFont default false;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  end;

...

procedure TPanel.SetScaleFont(const Value: boolean);
begin
  if Value <> FScaleFont then begin
    FScaleFont := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TPanel.Paint;
var
  lf: TLogFont;
  OldFont: HGDIOBJ;
begin
  if ScaleFont then begin
    Canvas.Font := Font;
    GetObject(Canvas.Font.Handle, SizeOf(lf), @lf);
    lf.lfHeight := Height;
    OldFont := SelectObject(Canvas.Handle, CreateFontIndirect(lf));
    while (Canvas.TextWidth(Caption) > ClientWidth) and (lf.lfHeight > 0) do begin
      Dec(lf.lfHeight);
      DeleteObject(SelectObject(Canvas.Handle, OldFont));
      OldFont := SelectObject(Canvas.Handle, CreateFontIndirect(lf));
    end;
    inherited;
    DeleteObject(SelectObject(Canvas.Handle, OldFont));
  end else
    inherited;
end;
```